# Adding changing values to a graphview

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I am attempting to analyze an array of bitmaps and follow the position of the brightest spot through each of the bitmaps. After analyzing each bitmap, I want to find the x and y position of the brightest(which I just set to be the average of the RGB values) spot and then graph that position on a graphview, and graph all max x,y values from each bitmap on the same graphview. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
private int pixels[];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(720);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(1280);

    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);


}

public void onImageGalleryClicked(View v) {

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    //where do we find the data
    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();
    //get a URI representation so android can deal with it
    Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath);
    //now created data, need to set data(where to look for it) and also what media we want to look for
    photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*");
    //for any type just use audio/* for any type
    //can be any number for startActivity, just needs to be a number not previously used. this gives it a unique ID so we know which is which
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
    //created random variable so that it is not previously used

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            //declare a stream to read the image data from the SD card
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
                Uri videouri = data.getData();
                retriever.setDataSource(this, videouri);
                String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
                long seconds = timeInmillisec / 1000;
                ArrayList<Bitmap> mylist = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++) {

                    Bitmap bArray = retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000000 * i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
                    mylist.add(bArray);

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                }

                series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

                for (int r = 0; r < mylist.size(); r++) {
                    Bitmap newbitmap = mylist.get(r);
                    int w = newbitmap.getWidth();
                    int h = newbitmap.getHeight();
                    pixels = new int[4 * w * h];
                    int a = 20; //this is the width of the smaller image that we are cropping to sum up
                    int b = 20; ////this is the length(height) of the smaller image that we are cropping to sum up

                    //getPixels() returns the complete int[] array of the source bitmap, so has to be initialized with the same length as the source bitmap's height x width.

                    int tempi = 0;
                    int tempj = 0;
                    double tempmax = 0;
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < h - b; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < w - a; j++) {
                            newbitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, j, i, a, b);
                            //summing code
                            for (int e = 0; e < a * b; e++) {
                                int red = (pixels[e] >> 16) & 0xff;
                                int green = (pixels[e] >> 8) & 0xff;
                                int blue = pixels[e] & 0xff;
                                double grey = (red + green + blue) / 3;
                                sum = sum + grey;
                            }

                            if (sum > tempmax) {
                                tempmax = sum;
                                tempi = i;
                                tempj = j;
                            }
                            sum = 0;
                        }
                    }
                     series.appendData(new DataPoint(tempj, tempi), true, mylist.size());
                     graph.addSeries(series);
                    tempi = 0;
                    tempj = 0;
                    tempmax = 0;
                }
                //picture width = 720 dp
                //picture height = 1280 dp
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

And here is the error I am getting

> 02-26 00:36:23.946 24443-24443/com.example.garrett.imageprocessingv4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.example.garrett.imageprocessingv4, PID: 24443
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=20, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/275 flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.garrett.imageprocessingv4/com.example.garrett.imageprocessingv4.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC.
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4556)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4599)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1715)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC.
>                                                                                              at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.checkValueOrder(BaseSeries.java:486)
>                                                                                              at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.appendData(BaseSeries.java:408)
>                                                                                              at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries.appendData(LineGraphSeries.java:646)
>                                                                                              at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.appendData(BaseSeries.java:464)
>                                                                                              at com.example.garrett.imageprocessingv4.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:123)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7322)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4552)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4599) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1715) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)